# Apptentive callback methods

Tags: android, ios, apptentive

Are there any Apptentive callback methods which inform us what is happening?

For example,

```
[[ATConnect sharedConnection] engage:@"completed_level" fromViewController:viewController];
```

tells Apptentive an event has occured, and now Apptentive might display an interaction.

After an event is logged, I would like to know whether:

- an interaction will be displayed
- an interaction is displaying
- interaction has been completed

Is there currently a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `engage:fromViewController:` indicates whether or not an interaction was shown for the event:

```
BOOL interactionShown = [[ATConnect sharedConnection] engage:@"event" fromViewController:vc];
if (interactionShown) {
    // Interaction (Survey, Rating Prompt, etc) was shown.
} else {
    // No interaction was shown.
}
```

You can also [use](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/issues/116) the method `willShowInteractionForEvent:` to know if an interaction will be shown the next time you engage an event:

```
BOOL availableSurvey = [[ATConnect sharedConnection] willShowInteractionForEvent:@"show_survey_event"];
if (availableSurvey) {
    // Show "Show Survey" button.
} else {
    // Hide "Show Survey" button.
}
```

Apptentive also posts some notifications that you can listen for and respond to via `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
/** Notification sent when Message Center unread messages count changes. */
extern NSString *const ATMessageCenterUnreadCountChangedNotification;

/** Notification sent when the user has agreed to rate the application. */
extern NSString *const ATAppRatingFlowUserAgreedToRateAppNotification;

/** Notification sent when a survey is shown. */
extern NSString *const ATSurveyShownNotification;

/** Notification sent when a survey is submitted by the user. */
extern NSString *const ATSurveySentNotification;
```

Finally, we are working some new features in this area. I will update this answer when those are available.

Comment: It would be useful for me to know when an interaction is complete and the Apptentive rate dialog has closed. Awaiting your update to this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @amit Would you mind emailing me? `peter & apptentive.com`. We'd like to discuss these upcoming features with some of the customers who will be using them to make sure they will meet your needs.

Comment: @pkamb: I need to check if event dialog is currently on screen and based on this i will check some conditions. Is there any way to know instead of didShown or will show kind of functions?